# Carousel via Vue (how use transition?)

Tags: vue.js, animation, vuejs2, carousel, transition

I beginner for Vue, and I trying make carousel via Vue.

I have the code: https://jsfiddle.net/z3m76w5r/4/ (example)

```
<style>
    .switch-enter-active,
    .switch-leave-active {
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .switch-enter {
      left: 100%;
    }

    .switch-leave,
    .switch-leave-to {
      left: -100%;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="banner">
    <transition name="switch">
      <banner class="content" v-bind:slide="currentSlide"></banner>
    </transition>
  <div>
```

I want animated my carousel. But my transition-vue don't work, despite I looked at the docs and manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why your transition using Vue build-in `<transition>` component doesn't work is because its [designed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) to work when some element/component is entering or leaving the DOM in context of:

- Conditional rendering (using `v-if`)
- Conditional display (using `v-show`)
- Dynamic components
- Component root nodes

Your image element is not entering or leaving DOM. Its just there and you are changing it's attributes (like url etc. - which cannot be animated in any way).

For your transition to work you need at least 2 `img` tags to exist in the DOM during the transition - one that is leaving the DOM and one that is entering the DOM. Easiest way to do this is by using `v-for` with `key` and `transition-group` instead of just `transition`. You just change the index of image, `v-for` will create new `img` element, apply "enter" transition to it and "leave" transition to old `img` element (for previous index)

You can find great example of that [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/create-image-slider/)

Comment: Thank you, Michal! Yep, I thought about I wrong used vue-transition.